# Python Pandas: How to broadcast an operation using apply without writing a secondary function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, apply

I have a column of data that contains strings, and I want to create a new column that takes only the first two characters from the corresponding data string.

It seems logical to use the `apply` function for this, but it doesn't work like expected. It does not even seem to be consistent with other uses of `apply`. See below.

```
In [205]: dfrm_test = pandas.DataFrame({"A":np.repeat("the", 10)})

In [206]: dfrm_test
Out[206]:
     A
0  the
1  the
2  the
3  the
4  the
5  the
6  the
7  the
8  the
9  the

In [207]: dfrm_test["A"].apply(lambda x: x+" cat")
Out[207]:
0    the cat
1    the cat
2    the cat
3    the cat
4    the cat
5    the cat
6    the cat
7    the cat
8    the cat
9    the cat
Name: A

In [208]: dfrm_test["A"].apply(lambda x: x[0:2])
Out[208]:
0    the
1    the
Name: A
```

Based on this, it appears that `apply` does nothing but perform the NumPy equivalent of whatever is called inside. That is, `apply` seems to execute the same thing as `arr + " cat"` in the first example. And if NumPy happens to broadcast that, then it will work. If not, then it won't.

But this seems to break from what `apply` promises in the docs. Below is the quotation for what pandas.Series.apply should expect:

> Invoke function on values of Series. Can be ufunc or Python function expecting only single values ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.Series.apply))

It says explicitly that it can accept Python functions expecting only single values. And the function that's not working (`lambda x: x[0:2]`) definitely satisfies that. It doesn't say that the single argument must be an array. And given that things like `numpy.sqrt` are commonly used for single inputs (so not exclusively arrays), it seems natural to expect Pandas to work with any such function.

Is there some way of using `apply` that I am missing here?

**Note:** I did write my own extra function below:

```
def ix2(arr):
    return np.asarray([x[0:2] for x in arr])
```

and I verified that this version *does* work with Pandas `apply`. But this is beside the point. It would be easier to write something that operated externally on top of a Series object than to have to constantly write wrappers that use list comprehensions to effectively loop over the contents of the Series. Isn't this specifically what `apply` is supposed to abstract away from the user?

I am using Pandas version 0.7.3, and it is on a workplace shared network, so there's no way to upgrade to the recent release.

**Added:**

I was able to confirm that this behavior changes from version 0.7.3 to version 0.8.1. In 0.8.1 it works as expected with no NumPy ufunc wrapper.

My guess is that in the code, someone was trying to use `numpy.vectorize` or `numpy.frompyfunc` within a try-except statement. Perhaps it did not work correctly with the particular lambda function I am using, and so in the `except` part of the code, it defaulted to just relying on generic NumPy broadcasting.

It would be great to get some confirmation on this from a Pandas developer, if possible. But in the meantime, the ufunc workaround should suffice.

Comment: Pandas 0.8 return for `dfrm_test["A"].apply(lambda x: x[0:2])` ten times `th`.

Comment: Are you confirming this is just a bug in version 7.2-1?? Please note that I mentioned at the bottom of the question that I cannot get away from using this version.

Comment: I don't know and I cannot check it now. If I had the same problem on 0.8, I could try to find a solution, but without 7.2 I cannot.

Comment: Correction: I have version 0.7.3. It was the Enthought distribution that I reported earlier. Same bug still occurs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround I can think of would be converting the Python function to `numpy.ufunc` with [`numpy.frompyfunc`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc):

```
numpy.frompyfunc((lambda x: x[0:2]), 1, 1)
```

and use this in `apply`:

```
In [50]: dfrm_test
Out[50]:
     A
0  the
1  the
2  the
3  the
4  the
5  the
6  the
7  the
8  the
9  the

In [51]: dfrm_test["A"].apply(np.frompyfunc((lambda x: x[0:2]), 1, 1))
Out[51]:
0    th
1    th
2    th
3    th
4    th
5    th
6    th
7    th
8    th
9    th
Name: A

In [52]: pandas.version.version
Out[52]: '0.7.3'

In [53]: dfrm_test["A"].apply(lambda x: x[0:2])
Out[53]:
0    the
1    the
Name: A
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `dfrm_test.A.map(lambda x: x[0:2])`

Comment: This works, but I consider it a workaround as well, since it doesn't address the fact that `apply` isn't working as promised. Can you verify that `map` will work in all the same situations where `apply` will work? I also don't like the inconsistency in going from `map` for a Series to `applymap` for a DataFrame.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that this is a "workaround" as `Series.map` is the intended method for element-wise operations. `Series.apply` will try passing the whole Series into the input function first and will fall back on element-wise operation only if an exception is raised.

Comment: That contradicts the docs for `apply`, as well as its 0.8.1 behavior, in which it successfully performs the elementwise version of my example above, whereas version 0.7.3 seems to use the logic you describe. Since `apply` should work in 0.7.3 as it does in 0.8.1 (according to the docs), that's why I think it's a workaround. `map` is fine, but `apply` should work.

Comment: I'm on github master and it does not work; it probably worked in 0.8.1 by accident. `apply` is designed so that you can apply a ufunc and get back a Series with the index intact. Take a look at the source code, it tries to call func(self) and wraps that in a try/except block and then calls map_infer in the except. In your example, the function you gave *can* take a Series and return a Series but doesn't do element-wise operations so the code cannot know to trigger the element-wise case. To be explicit that you want the input function to be applied element-wise, you have to use `Series.map`.

Comment: Though I do agree with you the docstring for apply is very unclear about this aspect. We can improve the documentation for apply.

Comment: In fact, by saying that `apply` can take any function that expect a *single* argument, it's not just unclear, but plain misleading. I'm glad you confirmed by hunch about that try-except block. So to be clear, we should use `apply` whenever we have a vectorized/ufunc already, and `map` when we literally want to apply an elementwise operation to a series?

Answer (score 1):

This works as of pandas 0.8.1:

```
In [47]: dfrm_test.A.str[:2]
Out[47]: 
0    th
1    th
2    th
3    th
4    th
5    th
6    th
7    th
8    th
9    th
Name: A
```